C# Undetected Chrome Driver Cloudflare Error
I'm trying to write a small automation script using C#. However, I'm getting stuck on a Cloudflare CAPTCHA on a website I'm using for the content. Despite my best efforts, I haven't been able to bypass it.
When using Selenium, the issue I'm facing is as follows: (Error: Having trouble?)

I don't encounter this error when using a normal browser. I compared my Selenium-driven page and my regular browser page using "https://bot.sannysoft.com" and found no differences.

On the C# side, I'm using the following NuGet package: "https://github.com/fysh711426/UndetectedChromeDriver"
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--disable-blink-features");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-web-security");
            options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.AddArgument("--allow-insecure-localhost");
            options.AddArgument("--allow-running-insecure-content");

using (var driver = UndetectedChromeDriver.Create(options, driverExecutablePath: await new ChromeDriverInstaller().Auto(), userDataDir: path, prefs: prefs))

I've tried toggling the parameters above in different sequences, but nothing seems to work. I've also tried using some spoofing extensions in Selenium, but they didn't help either.
I'm confused as to why I can perform these actions in a regular browser, but not with Selenium. I would appreciate any help.
Edit:
Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?
I did some tests based on this comment and discovered something. On the website 'https://deviceandbrowserinfo.com/are_you_a_bot', my Selenium page is detected as a bot :/ I noticed that the only difference from my normal browser is the 'isAutomatedWithCDP' value being true. I'm currently experimenting with ways to make it false.

This question is similar to: Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Selenium generated events are "synthetic" and can be detected in various ways.  (one of them is the isTrusted property of events)  The presence of WireProtocol session and/or dev tools protocol usage can also be detected.
